# Max element of input iterator range

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator

I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452356/why-does-stdmax-element-require-a-forwarditerator) on why [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) requires a [`ForwardIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) (as apposed to an [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)). Having a `max_element`-like algorithm for `InputIterator` would be useful, as it could then be used with objects like `std::istream_iterator` or `boost::transform_iterator`.

I came up with the following algorithm for this:

```
#include <iterator>   // std::iterator_traits, std::advance
#include <stdexcept>  // std::logic_error
#include <algorithm>  // std::for_each
#include <functional> // std::less
#include <utility>    // std::move

template <typename InputIterator, typename Compare>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
max_input(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Compare comp)
{
    if (first == last) throw std::logic_error {"max_input given empty range"};

    using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type;

    ValueType result {*first};

    std::advance(first, 1);

    std::for_each(first, last, [&result, comp] (ValueType curr) {
        if (comp(result, curr)) result = std::move(curr);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream str("0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.2 0.0 0.1");

    const auto max = max_input(std::istream_iterator<double>(str), std::istream_iterator<double>());

    std::cout << "max is " << max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for general feedback/improvements, especially on the decision to `throw` for an empty range. I was also deliberating whether the algorithm should also return the index of the maximum (e.g. in a `std::pair`).

Answer (score 8):

**Don't use a lambda**

This code:

```
std::for_each(first, last, [&result, comp] (ValueType curr) {
    if (comp(result, curr)) result = std::move(curr);
});
```

is just a lot messier than the non-lambda equivalent:

```
for (; first != last; ++first) {
    ValueType cur = *first;
    if (comp(result, cur)) {
        result = std::move(cur);
    }
}
```

I don't see the advantage in the lambda.

**Avoid the copy**

Once you advance an input iterator, all earlier iterators are invalidated. But you can dereference the same one multiple times. In this case, you're incurring an unnecessary copy of `ValueType`, you can just write:

```
for (; first != last; ++first) {
    if (comp(result, *first)) {
        result = std::move(*first);
    }
}
```

**Move iterators**

Dereference likely returns a `const T&` - so you probably want to wrap the iterators in [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) first. That will actually let you move-from the iterator, instead of looking like you're moving from and actually copying from.

**advance is excessive**

You can just write:

```
ValueType result{*first++};
```

Or:

```
ValueType result{*first};
++first;
```

There's no need for `advance()` - you know `operator++` is supported.

**Throwing on empty range**

Honestly, I'd prefer it just be undefined behavior and avoid the first check. Let the user deal with it. That's just a personal preference though.

Additionally, you could return an `optional<ValueType>`, returning `none` if the range is empty.

**Defer to `std::max_element`?**

Since `std::max_element` is more efficient than yours for forward iterators, it'd be nice to defer to it if you're given a forward iterator:

```
template <class It, class Cmp>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
max_input(It first, It last, Cmp mp) {
    // possibly check empty range and throw here, if that's what you want
    return max_input(first, last, cmp, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category{});
}

template <class It, class Cmp>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
max_input(It first, It last, Cmp cmp, std::input_iterator_tag) {
    /* your implementation */
}

template <class It, class Cmp>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
max_input(It first, It last, Cmp cmp, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
    return *std::max_element(it, last, cmp);
}
```

**Excessive commenting**

Avoid this sort of commenting style:

```
#include <iterator>   // std::iterator_traits, std::advance
#include <stdexcept>  // std::logic_error
#include <algorithm>  // std::for_each
#include <functional> // std::less
#include <utility>    // std::move
```

It's just verbose and provides no value.

Comment: Is there a reason you made a copy of the `ValueType` in your non-lambda implementation? Wouldn't it be more efficient to skip making the copy of that element on each `for` loop iteration and just do:
`if (comp(result, *first)) {
        ValueType cur = *first;
        result = std::move(*first);
    }`

Comment: @TamerCpp The original copied too - I just... copied... the code. But yeah, you're right, updated the answer.

Comment: The reason I chose to make an unconditional copy rather than multiple dereferences was that we cannot be sure of the complexity of the dereference. e.g. I believe boost::transform_iterator applies its functor at dereference rather than on increment. But I guess that could be the callers responsibility.