# minimax of input iterator range

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I previously posted a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114876/max-element-of-input-iterator-range) on finding the maximum value of an [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) range. For completeness, I thought it would be useful to post an implementation that finds the minimum & maximum values, in a similar way to `std::minmax_element`.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename InputIt, typename Compare>
    auto minmax_input(InputIt first, InputIt last, Compare comp, std::input_iterator_tag)
    {
        using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;

        std::pair<ValueType, ValueType> result {*first, *first};

        if (++first == last) return result;

        if (comp(*first, result.first)) {
            result.first = *first;
        } else {
            result.second = *first;
        }

        while (++first != last) {
            auto prev = *first;
            if (++first == last) {
                if (comp(prev, result.first))
                    result.first = std::move(prev);
                else if (!comp(prev, result.second))
                    result.second = std::move(prev);
                break;
            } else {
                if (comp(*first, prev)) {
                    if (comp(*first, result.first))
                        result.first = *first;
                    if (!comp(prev, result.second))
                        result.second = std::move(prev);
                } else {
                    if (comp(prev, result.first))
                        result.first = std::move(prev);
                    if (!comp(*first, result.second))
                        result.second = *first;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    template <typename ForwardIt, typename Compare>
    auto minmax_input(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp, std::forward_iterator_tag)
    {
        const auto itr_result = std::minmax_element(first, last, comp);
        return std::make_pair(*itr_result.first, *itr_result.second);
    }
} // namespace detail

template <typename InputIt, typename Compare = std::less<void>>
auto minmax_input(InputIt first, InputIt last, Compare comp = Compare {})
{
    return detail::minmax_input(first, last, comp, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category {});
}
```

As this will presumably be used mostly on input streams, I also thought to provide this helper method:

```
#include <istream>

template <typename T>
auto minmax_stream(std::istream& in)
{
    return minmax_input(std::istream_iterator<T> {in}, std::istream_iterator<T> {});
}
```

Used like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream ss {"0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.2 0.05 0.1"};

    const auto minmax = minmax_stream<double>(ss);

    std::cout << "minmax is (" << minmax.first << ", " << minmax.second << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @greybeard You're right, there was an error - corrected now. I don't believe this is "reinventing-the-wheel"; this is a problem not solved by any algorithm in the standard library.

Comment: A pity Zeta withdrew his whole answer: one of numerous points I agree with has been use of more telling names for the extrema and construction of the pair at return. Not really easy with move semantics, I guess I'd choose (non-rvalue-)references instead of _the real thing_ (just `auto`) or (as [your reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) shows) try and keep the iterator before it was advanced - comment your choice? Nagging me in both renditions is the repetition of _the non-pair comparisons_ at the beginning and end of the sequence - beware a non-answer.

Comment: @greybeard I agree; Zita's answer was still useful. But it's not possible to keep the iterator (or a reference) to the previous iterator - that's the whole point of implementing this algorithm for InputIterator (single pass). I don't really understand the repetition in the algorithm either, but it's the way it's implemented in libcpp...

Answer (score 1):

(This is an extended (and formatted…) comment (*don't like the repetition of* the non-pair comparisons at the beginning and end of the sequence). Not having *used* C++ in a dozen years, I'm hopeless with *move semantics*, for one. (And not quite destined to review C++ postings…))

Let me try something about *the non-pair comparisons*:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename Compare>
auto minmax_input(InputIt first, InputIt last, Compare comp, std::input_iterator_tag)
{
    using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;

    auto const
        &minimum = *first,
        &maximum = minimum;

    while (++first != last) {
        auto &prev = *first;
        if (++first == last) { // left with half a pair: prev
            if (comp(prev, minimum))
                minimum = prev;
            else if (!comp(prev, maximum))
                maximum = prev;
            break;
        }
        if (comp(*first, prev)) {
            if (comp(*first, minimum))
                minimum = *first;
            if (!comp(prev, maximum))
                maximum = prev;
        } else {
            if (comp(prev, minimum))
                minimum = prev;
            if (!comp(*first, maximum))
                maximum = *first;
        }
    }

    return std::pair<ValueType, ValueType> {minimum, maximum};
}
```

(Come to think of it, I don't like the symmetrical pairs of comparisons in the loop…)

```
        auto min_max = std::minmax(one, *first);
        if (comp(min_max.first, minimum))
            minimum = min_max.first;
        if (!comp(min_max.second, maximum))
            maximum = min_max.second;
```